# Sorting by SortField.Type.LONG with Hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm creating a search page for my webapp and I need to be able to select the field I want to sort on the direction of the sort. Like so :

[image]

It looks simple but I can't get it working.

If I set `id` as the property I get the following error :

```
fullTextQuery.setSort(new Sort(new SortField("id",SortField.Type.LONG,true)));
```

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000307: Sort type LONG is not compatible with string type of field 'id'.
```

Even though my field is :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@SortableField
private Long id;
```

Do you have any idea why my "id" field is a string in the Hibernate Search index and how do I change it?

EDIT :

My second problem is when was when I wanted to sort by relevance. Normally you'd just use `SortField.FIELD_SCORE` as your `SortField` and it will sort by score. But I want to set the direction of the sort. So I looked into the decompiled `SortField` class and I found where `FIELD_SCORE` is defined. And it looks like that :

```java
static {
    FIELD_SCORE = new SortField((String)null, SortField.Type.SCORE);
    FIELD_DOC = new SortField((String)null, SortField.Type.DOC);
    ...
}
```

The solution is to use :

```
fullTextQuery.setSort(new Sort(new SortField(SortField.FIELD_SCORE.getField(),SortField.Type.SCORE,true)));
```

Comment: Just for the record, what does `new SortField("id", SortField.Type.STRING, true)` give?

Comment: It works with Type STRING but the first element's id is 100 in ascending order and the first in descending order is 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't sort on the ID directly. The ID is always of type string internally, so sorting on that field will result in unexpected results.

You need to define a separate field, make that field sortable, and sort on that field instead of the id:

```java
@Id
@Field(name = "id_sort", index = Index.NO)
@SortableField(forField = "id_sort")
private Long id;
```

Second... do yourself a favor and use use the Sort DSL. It should catch such problems early, and makes all kinds of sorts easier to write.

For a sort by field value:

```java
QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Book.class).get();
Query luceneQuery = /* ... */;
FullTextQuery query = s.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, Book.class );
Sort sort = builder.sort().byField("id_sort").asc().createSort();
query.setSort(sort);
List results = query.list();
```

And for a sort by reversed relevance (ascending score):

```java
QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Book.class).get();
Query luceneQuery = /* ... */;
FullTextQuery query = s.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, Book.class );
Sort sort = builder.sort().byScore().asc().createSort();
query.setSort(sort);
List results = query.list();
```

More info in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-sorting).

Note however that the least relevant hits are likely to be completely useless, so putting them first in your result list is highly dubious...

Answer (score 0):

The field `id` must be reserved by Hibernate Search and be of type string.

I changed my field definition to :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Field(name = "identifier", analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES)
@SortableField(forField = "identifier")
private Long id;
```

and I sort by field `identifier` instead of `id` and it works.